# Parse SNMP STRING in datacollection

Tags: opennms

I have an SNMP device that is return temperature as a string.

`SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.45501.1.3.8.0 = STRING: "+27.3"`

Is there a way to parse out the value to persist it for graphing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hrm - you should be able to set the type to "octetstring" but I'm not sure about the "+" sign.

i.e.:

```
<group name="micro-instruments-temperature" ifType="all">
      <mibObj oid=".1.3.6.1.4.1.45501.1.3.8" instance="0" alias="microTemp" type="octetstring"/>
</group>
```

Assign that group to a systemDef and see if it works. You can also make the instance a generic resource if needed.

Check out the "hwg.xml" file in the "datacollection" directory for a similar entry for an HWG temperature sensor (although I don't believe they sign the temperature value).

Comment: I realised I had the "instance" in the OID, once I fixed that per your example, it's working like a charm and seems happy with the the + sign